# Why docker volume needs absolute path instead of relative?

Tags: docker

See the below example

```sh
desktop:~/trash/sample/python/work$ echo "Hello world" > hello
desktop:~/trash/sample/python/work$ docker run --rm -it -v "hello":/home/hello alpine cat /home/hello
cat: read error: Is a directory
desktop:~/trash/sample/python/work$ docker run --rm -it -v "./hello":/home/hello alpine cat /home/hello
docker: Error response from daemon: create ./hello: "./hello" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.
desktop:~/trash/sample/python/work$ docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD/hello":/home/hello alpine cat /home/hello
Hello world
```

As you can see only the last option i.e. absolute path works rest are failed.

Comment: Use docker-compose. There you can use relative paths. (Sorry, no answer to your question though)

Comment: Probably ultimately because the low-level mount(2) system call will need an absolute path.  Docker also chose some syntactic differences; your first command with no slash at all on the left-hand side mounts a Docker named volume and not a host directory.

Comment: Docker is a client/server program. The path is used on the server, which can be a different host from the client. Ultimately this was a design decision of the CLI, and compose has made other design decisions.